# vuejs - bind to component data

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js, components

I've created a simple component:
https://jsfiddle.net/s08yhcda/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <button-counter>My counter: <span v-text="count"></span></button-counter>
</div>

// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++"><slot></slot></button>'
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

Yet I cannot bind to the inner component data (counter). How can a component expose its data to the `<slot>` scope? I know the "events up, props down" idea. But still I thought it would be possible to bind component data inside its scope (inside the `<button-counter>` element)

I prefer not using event for something that simple. Any other way?

Comment: Where you try to access the counter variable isn't inside button counter, it inside `#app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

## Using events

This is usually the best method, as it is expected by other Vue developer

```js
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        click() {
            this.count++;
            this.$emit('input', this.count);
        },
    },
    template: '<button v-on:click="click"><slot></slot></button>'
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0,
        };
    },
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button-counter @input="count = $event">My counter: <span v-text="count"></span></button-counter>
</div>
```

## Using refs:

```js
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        click() {
            this.count++;
        },
    },
    template: '<button v-on:click="click"><slot></slot></button>'
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            mounted: false,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.mounted = true;
    },
    computed: {
        count() {
            return this.mounted ? this.$refs.counter.count : 0;
        },
    },
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button-counter ref="counter">My counter: <span v-text="count"></span></button-counter>
</div>
```

## Using `slot-scope`

Using slot scope, you can pass multiple arguments to the parent slot:

```js
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        click() {
            this.count++;
        },
    },
    template: '<button v-on:click="click"><slot :count="count"></slot></button>'
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <button-counter>
        <span slot-scope="prop">
            My counter:
            <span v-text="prop.count"></span>
        </span>
    </button-counter>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't like these ways, I would probably have to find a hack, or to resort to using events. I found a library 'vee-validate' which actually does push data to the parent component, any idea how it is done?

Comment: @user3599803 They migth do it from the parent by looking over [`$children`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) or from the child by walking the chain of [`$parent`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent)

Comment: I can't figure out how it is possible, vee-validate actually injects a reactive property to a vue instance, couldn't find how it's done

Answer (score 1):

You can send data to the slot. Look at this example:

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++"><slot :count="count" /></button>'
})

<div id="app">
  <button-counter>
    <template scope="props">
      My counter: <span>{{ props.count }}</span>
    </template>
  </button-counter>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s08yhcda/2/